# Pregunta licenciamiento, MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tenia una pequeña inquietud, como ya sabemos oracle adquirio mysql, ahora pretendo usar MySQL Workbench, pero no si se lo puedo usar de manera gratuita en mi empresa para desarrollar, que opinan ustedes?

Comment: Será que hablas de MySQL Server, pues Workbench es una especie de IDE para desarrollo, segundo deberías leer sobre el licenciamiento del mismo aquí: [MySQL prices](https://www.mysql.com/products/) y aquí sobre la [community edition](https://www.mysql.com/products/community/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias [ediciones de MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html):

- Community (GPL)
- Standard (Commercial)
- Enterprise (Comercial)

Si estás usando la Community (CE), puedes emplearla en tu empresa de forma gratuita ya que la licencia GPLv2 lo permite. A tener en cuenta es que si estás haciendo una aplicación para distribuir de forma comercial, [la licencia GPL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) te obliga a publicar el código hecho con esas herramientas. Hay gente que lo cumple, otros no, pero si tu software se volviera popular y hacen una investigación, entonces te obligarán a hacerlo.

Otras versiones, Standard (SE) o Enterprise (EE), tienen características adicionales y te otorgan la capacidad de poder blindar todo tu trabajo si quieres, pero pasando previamente por la caja registradora de Oracle. Si tu empresa ha comprado una versión de MySQL SE o EE entonces puedes usar el Workbench correspondiente.

Concluyendo: Puedes usar la versión Community (CE) [de forma gratuita en tu empresa](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,606940,606963,quote=1).

Comment: Muchas gracias aeportugal